# Message: Error: NameResolutionFailure when using the getstream SDK

Tags: getstream-io

I got the exception "Message: Error: NameResolutionFailure" when calling the getstream sdk on Xamarin.iOS app.

This does not happen all the time , but it happens quite often.

[Please check this link for the detail error message of the exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KrGy.png)

Following is the code where the exception happens

```
        var userFeed = client.Feed("timeline", "id");
        var activities =  await userFeed.GetActivities(0, 15);
```

Is there anyway to resolve this issue?  Please help

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests that the OS is unable to resolve the DNS correctly. The most common cause for this is bad ISP DNS servers.

The simplest solution is to pick Google or Cloudflare DNS and configure your network (ie. your router DHCP settings or similar) to use them.

Google DNS: `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`

Cloudflare DNS: `1.1.1.1`